# Is it possible to remove the blank part at the top of a fragment, What is the purpose of this part?

Tags: android, android-fragments

the top of the fragment has always a blank part [image: screenshot]

What is the purpose of that part ? Is it possible to remove it ?

I didn't find any similar problem. maybe the problem is in my method to call it :

```
ProductListFragment productFragment = new ProductListFragment();
productFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "productSelection");
```

Comment: Show code of **ProductListFragment**

Comment: you seem to be using dialog fragment.. you can use getDialog.setTitle("your title"); to fill it up.. or use getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); to remove the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that your `Fragment` is a `DialogFragment`? If so, use

```
getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```